# Toggling one element disables the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, html-table

So I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/GqS7W/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggler").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
}); });
```

And I applied it to my table, but I need that when one button is pressed the others hide, like a menu, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('tr[class^=cat]').hide();
        $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! it's exactly what I was looking for!, but I wonder, could it be possible to add some transition or effect to the toggling?

Comment: Yes you can; you can change the [duration](http://api.jquery.com/show) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

quite simple  i have updated http://jsfiddle.net/GqS7W/832/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggler").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).siblings('.item').slideUp();
   $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).slideDown();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggler").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();       
    $(".toggler").parent().parent().toggle();
    $(this).parent().parent().show();        
    $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
});
});
```